# Jetty Runner root redirect to context

Tags: jetty, jetty-9

I am running my application using jetty-runner.jar.
For my application I am using context path for example /app.

The problem is:

If I open root I am getting

> No context on this server matched or handled this request. Contexts
>   known to this server are: ...

So if I want to open application I need to go to /app.

What I want to do is to redirect to /app if user tries to access /

To run application, I am running this command:

```
java $JVMARGS -jar jetty-runner.jar --port 8989 jetty-context.xml
```

In my jetty-context.xml I have configuration for my app

```
<Configure id="wac" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="contextPath"><SystemProperty name="contextPath"/></Set>
    <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="warFile"/></Set>
    <Get name="securityHandler">
        ...
```

Comment: Try: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/rewrite-handler.html